# Dictionary as choices in choicefield inside forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

Im giving the choices for a choicefield in forms.py as a dictionary. I've imported my dictionaries page as dicto.

```
da=[dicto.country_array]
country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=da,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control m-b', 'id':'country_sel'}))
```

In the template, I'm getting ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).
How do i get the choices correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Choices must be an iterable (tuple or list) as you can see in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices)

So you'd need to define something like;

```
country = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=[
        ('fr', 'France'),
        ('gb', 'United Kingdom'),
        ('us', 'United States')
    ],
    widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control m-b',
            'id':'country_sel'
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Found out a way. changed this> da=[dicto.country_array] to this> da=dicto.country_array.items()

Comment: @SayYes that'll do it. If you're using python 2 some people might argue about the efficiency of doing it like that, but it's a fairly common way.